# How to stop MBP from disconnecting external display when screen is locked?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, sleep-wake, screen-lock

**Setup**

- MBP, 13", 2017, with touch bar;
- MacOS 10.15.4 (Catalina);
- LG 27UD88-W external display;
- Display is connected over USB-C -- USB-C cable. Signal and charging over the same cable.

**Problem**

Every time I lock the screen, the external display loses signal a few seconds later. This is a problem to me because reconnecting the display on wake up causes numerous annoyances. Corporate apps like Citrix will even regularly crash when the external monitor gets disconnected.

I'd like to make my mac to keep signal with the display when locked.

I can't find any useful options neither in power not display settings. I can't find anything useful in the internets either.

**More details**

The MBP keeps getting charged through the monitor, so at least power is still on.

Even though I'm on MacOS 10.15.4, it's been a problem since at least 10.13.

[image]